# Generating a custom id on model create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to generate a custom ID for my model based on the database ID the is assigned by default in Rails.

That is, I have the following model:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

When saved, a `Teacher` gets an `id` automatically from the database. I've added another column called `user_id` which is a string; I'm trying to generate a new id that's based on the default one (i.e. if the `teacher.id` is `1`, then the `user_id` becomes `T-0001` or something to that effect.

I've tried using the `after_save` method; but that isn't very helpful; I would end up updating the new column even if I didn't need to (say after an update or something). The `after_create` callback won't work either as the `id` hasn't actually been assigned yet by the database.

Comment: Once user_id can be generated from id, I don't think you should have it in your database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not, instead of storing it in your database, you just create a method that retuns that value? Something like:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  ...
  def user_id
    "T-#{self.id.to_s.rjust(4, '0')}"
  end
end
```

If you really want to store it in the database, you should use `after_save` checking if the value already was generated:

```
class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :generate_user_id
  ...
  private
  def generate_user_id
    self.update(user_id: "T-#{self.id.to_s.rjust(4, '0')}") if self.user_id.nil?
  end
end
```

Comment: That sound great, but at the same time I'd like the user to login via that ID as well, so I think a more persistent solution is better.

Comment: Perfect! Checking if the id was already nil or not completely slipped my mind; I was under the assumption that I would need to update the id everytime I saved the model (including update actions)